# uploadify doesn't upload to server

Tags: php, upload, uploadify

it shows no error and its look like working. but it doesnt upload images to server.

same code working on localhost.

read something about this problem but still have no solution:

same problem:

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/6974/upload-ok-but-file-not-in-target-folder/p1

http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/5527/upload-does-not-work-no-errors/p1

Jquery:

```
$("#fileUpload2").fileUpload({
    'uploader': 'uploadify/uploader.swf',
    'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
    'script': 'uploadify/upload.php',
    'folder': '/files',
    'multi': true,
    'buttonText': 'start upl',
    'checkScript': 'uploadify/check.php',
    'displayData': 'speed',
    'simUploadLimit': 2,
    'onComplete':function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data){
        foto=foto+fileObj.name;

        }
});
```

upload.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_GET['folder'] . '/';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $ff= $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    echo $ff;
    // Uncomment the following line if you want to make the directory if it doesn't exist
    // mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}

echo '1';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got invalid error handling on there. Checking for a non-empty $_FILES is **NOT** the proper way to check for a successful upload. Failed uploads will still populate data into $_FILES. At bare minimum, you should have

```
if ($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['Filedata']['error'];
}
```

and then see what error code you get: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

You are also using the user-provided filename DIRECTLY in your move() call, allowing malicious user to scribble their uploaded file **ANYWHERE** on your server, leaving you wide open for a complete system takeover. Do not put this code onto a live website until you take the time to learn basic PHP (and web) security.